# How to parse a file that contains a long list of numbers in each line?

Tags: c, file-io

I have file like below:

1 2 300 500  5 117  5  90 45  34 ----  --------------    34566

7 8  16 8    39  167   80  90 38                        4555

and so on
How could I get each numbers and store a 2-dimensional array?

so far I can read the line using the fgets() function.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
char buffer[1024];
 fp = fopen("Input.txt","r"); 
if(fp!=NULL)
{
  while(fgets(buffer,1024,fp)!=NULL)
  {
    // i need help here

   } 
 }
```

Is there another method of solving (better than this) rather than using fgets()?

Comment: Read up on **sscanf()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    //Either the two-pass or ensure dynamically allocate and expand by `realloc` if size of the array can't be determined in advance, 

    static int array[20][20];
    int row=0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char buffer[1024];
    fp = fopen("Input.txt","r"); 
    if(fp!=NULL) {
        while(fgets(buffer,1024,fp)!=NULL){
            char *p = buffer, *endp;
            long num;
            int col = 0;
            do{
                num = strtol(p, &endp, 10);
                if(*endp == ' ' || *endp == '\n' || *endp == '\0'){
                    array[row][col++] = num;
                }
                p = endp + 1;
            }while(*endp != '\n' && *endp != '\0');
            ++row;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be something like:

```
int i = 0;
int num[20];
while (buffer[i] != '\0')
{
  int j = 0;
  char a[80];
  while (buffer[i] != ' ')
  {
    a[j] = buffer[i];
    ++j;
    ++i;
  }
  if (buffer[i] == '\0')
    break;
  a[j] = '\0';
  const char* b = &a[0];
  num[i] = strtol(b, NULL, 10);
  ++i;
}
```

...though memory management is dirty here. Gotta work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Working code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str_avail;
    char *token;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char buffer[1024];
    char buffer2[1024];

    fp = fopen("test.txt","r"); 
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(buffer,1024,fp)!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            str_avail = strpbrk(buffer, ":");
            if(*buffer == '\n')
                continue;
            strcpy(buffer2, str_avail+2);
            token = strtok(buffer2, " ");
            while(token != NULL){
                    printf("%s\n", token);
                        token = strtok (NULL, " ");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```